# Multiple dex files define Lokhttp3/ResponseBody$BomAwareReader

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm trying to include the retrofit logging interceptor into my app and I'm getting this error:

```
`Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: 
 Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define 
 Lokhttp3/ResponseBody$BomAwareReader;`
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
`implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1"
 implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:12.0.1"
 implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1"
 implementation "com.android.support:design:27.1.1"
 implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1"
 implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.1"
 implementation "com.android.support:preference-v14:27.1.1"
 implementation "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1"
 implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1"
 implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
 implementation "com.android.support:leanback-v17:27.1.1"
 implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
 implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1"
 implementation "com.android.support:transition:27.1.1"
 implementation('com.swrve.sdk.android:swrve:5.2.0') {
     exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
 }
 implementation 'com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3:interactivemedia:3.8.2'
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.1'
 implementation files('libs/retrofit-2.3.0.jar')
 implementation files('libs/okhttp-3.8.1.jar')
 implementation files('libs/okio-1.13.0.jar')`
```

Comment: did you enable multidex ? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html?hl=pt-br

Comment: I did, and I just found the problem, somebody else was adding another version of the library further down and I didn't see it